# When to use type parameters within Scala?

Tags: scala, types

Are functions which involve type paramters limited in their use to collections ?
Such as appending, removing and sorting of Lists of generic types ?

I find I rarely ever encounter a use case for type parameters but at same time feel that I may be missing something ?

This code :

```
object customType {

  class MyClass[A] = {

    def doFun(a : A) = {

    }

  }

}
```

The method doFun cannot actually perform anything on the type A (other than List operations)
as its type is unbouned/not known ?

Type parameters appear to be very powerful, but I would like to extend their use to not just type checking that
collections contain the correct types at compile time. Are there other common examples/patterns that display the use of
type parameters ?

Comment: You may want to choose which question you want an answer to. Or ask multiple question on Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The short answer is that it might not be useful to you if you are an application programmer. More often you will end up using a library that has used type parameters. They are useful for solving general patterns of coding (thus generics), thus why they are often in library code where the writer does not know what the end user will need.

That being said, you might want to read up on [type classes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_class), as they can be a decent way to solve some dependency problems even at application level coding. And, last...the pattern that types come in most handy for is the ...duh duh duh... monad pattern :), which is not nearly as scary as it's made out to be.